# jsp:setProperty equivalent for servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

Is there an equivalent to:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="beanName" property="*"/>
```

for servlets?

Something that will auto-populate the bean from inside a servlet using the request parameters? I'm refactoring a JSP-only application and would like to move some of the code to servlets. For a bunch of tragic reasons, we are not able (right now) to use any frameworks to make this easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use external libraries? If so, [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) would help you a lot.

**Update:** Now that you've confirmed you can use this approach:
The method you're looking for is [BeanUtils.populate()](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html). There is an [example](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html) here (chapter 4.2) on how to use it to map request parameters.

Comment: I can -  so I'll check this out.

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to do it, but there is nothing there from you out of the box. It would be pretty easy to write a little helper object to do using reflection